# What are the current requirements for compiling a module in Ubutu LTS

Tags: drivers, kernel

There are a few other similar questions that all end with

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
```

I am trying to follow this

https://devarea.com/linux-kernel-development-creating-a-proc-file-and-interfacing-with-user-space/#.YMTLWTqxVH5

Which has headers such as

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>   
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
```

no matter how I compile, the downloaded headers I get a chain of more missing deps.

e.g
.

```
gcc -Wall -Werror  
-I/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-55/include 
-I/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-55/arch/x86/include/ 
-I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-55-generic/arch/x86/include/generated 
-I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-55-generic/include 
-I/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-55/include/uapi 
-c hello.c
```

I feel like I'm missing something. Is there any Ubuntu dev guide for kernel modules that includes how to get the required source and tools to compile a simple hello world module in 20.04LTS.

Comment: Is there any improvement if you do: `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic`?

Comment: The post you linked looks like part 2 of a series - in the first part [Linux Kernel Development and Writing a Simple Kernel Module](https://devarea.com/linux-kernel-development-and-writing-a-simple-kernel-module/) the author shows how to do build the module - in particular, scroll down to *To build the module we need the following Makefile* - it's not just a matter of running `gcc` as you would for a userland C program